# Cannot Append options Dynamically in Input Select

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select

I am getting input element options through ajax and appending them into Select element. When I use element Id to append the options they are being appended correctly but when I try to achieve the same thing through class the select element is replaced by the options.

I don't understand why there is difference between appending options through id and class while they are the attribute of the same element.

**Here is my code**

```
<script>
function getAllSubLob(lob_id, element)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{route('getAllSubLob')}}',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'lob_id' : lob_id,
            },
            success: function (response) {

                $(element).val('default').selectpicker('deselectAll');

                $(element).html(response);
                $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is what happens to my input element when I add options through class
[image]

I have multiple elements to which I want to append the options that's why I am using class selector

**HTML Code When Option Appended Through Id**

```
    <td>
   <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select select-lob form-control form-control-sm">
      <select id="abcd" class="select-lob form-control form-control-sm selectpicker" tabindex="-98">
         <option value="1">CSG</option>
         <option value="2">CP_D</option>
         <option value="3">Server</option>
         <option value="4">Network</option>
         <option value="5">Storage</option>
         <option value="6">HCI</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="abcd" title="CSG">
         <div class="filter-option">
            <div class="filter-option-inner">
               <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">CSG</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu " role="combobox" style="max-height: 330px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 116px;">
         <div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 312px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 98px;">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show">
               <li class="selected active"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item selected active" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">CSG</span></a></li>
               <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">CP_D</span></a></li>
               <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Server</span></a></li>
               <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Network</span></a></li>
               <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Storage</span></a></li>
               <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">HCI</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

**HTML Code When Option Appended Through Class**

```
<td>
   <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select select-lob form-control form-control-sm"> 
      <option value="1">CSG</option>
      <option value="2">CP_D</option>
      <option value="3">Server</option>
      <option value="4">Network</option>
      <option value="5">Storage</option>
      <option value="6">HCI</option>
   </div>
</td>
```

Removing the select picker has no effect. Still facing the problem.

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code?  eg what's `element` when it works and when it doesn't work and what's the HTML that `element` refers to (when it works/doesn't work).  And does it work/not work without the 3rd party selectpicker?

Comment: Can you also provide details as to which "selectpicker" you are using?

Comment: I have updated the queston

Comment: What you see in js console? Is this syntax correct - '{{route('getAllSubLob')}}' ?

Comment: I have no error in console.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for this problem?

Comment: not able to find enough code to debug. can you please provide more details.